# Make one component a static header in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular 2.

I have three components I'm calling on a single page. One of which is meant to be a header.

Example:

```
<page-title title="{{title}}"></page-title>
<users></users>
<other></other>
```

I'm trying to make the page-title component static, so when a user scrolls, it becomes a static banner at the tope of the page and the users and other's content scrolls under it.

My question is - "Do you apply the style to the component tag?

Comment: this one is difficult for anyone to answer. Do you have a plnkr?

Comment: Hi pixelbits, I don't, but will try to put one together.